# IntelliJ, How to show git diff before pull ( such as Team Synchronizing in Eclipse )

Tags: git, intellij-idea, synchronization

I'm using IntelliJ with git. I just want to show differences from git remote repository before pulling.

Eclipse supports team synchronizing view, so that i can see which file i have to pull or commit and also show differences from local to remote, before push or pull.

How to see like eclipse in IntelliJ?
I just want to see files ( which i will pull or push ).

I've local change or show diff (CTRL+D) in IntelliJ 
but it only show files (which i changed files in local repository )

Answer (score 1):

You can do a fetch instead of a pull. This will update the upstream/master branch but not your local master branch. You can then see in the Log tab the changes.

But remember that you'll then need to manually merge upstream/master to apply the changes to your local copy. You can also run a pull to do that, but if there were further changes they'll be applied as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to show differences from git remote repository before pulling.

Just to be precise, Git is a Distributed VCS so the repository is local and all diff is done in the local repository. To see the diff you want, you have to download the data from the remote repo first. This is done by `git fetch`. Fetch is also executed as part of git pull.

So, as noted, you can do fetch (in IntelliJ it is in the menu VCS - Git - Fetch) and then compare your branch with its upstream.